# Using method in javascript

Tags: javascript, methods

Supouse I have the next method to insert a value in a cell of a table:

```
var objeto = { 
    row: function(rowId){ 
        return { 
            cell: function(cellClass){ 
                return {
                  set: function(val){ 
                     document.querySelector(rowId+' '+cellClass).innerHTML = val;
                  }
                }
                //Or just return the value
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I know to insert the value, I need use:

```
objeto.row('#rowid').cell('.cellclass').set('hello');
```

But If I want to get the cell value using:

```
var data = objeto.row('#rowid').cell('.cellclass');
```

What's the method I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following structure:

```
var objeto2 = { 
    row: function(rowId){ 
        return { 
            cell: function(cellClass){ 
                return {
                    value: function(val){ 
                        if (val) {
                            document.querySelector(rowId + ' ' + cellClass).innerHTML = val;
                        } else {
                            return document.querySelector(rowId + ' ' + cellClass).innerHTML;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

objeto.row('#rowid').cell('.cellclass').value('hello'); // set value
objeto.row('#rowid').cell('.cellclass').value();        // get value
```

Comment: But here you delete the 'set' function

Comment: @Newton Isn't it better this way? You only need one function to set and get.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is return type of any function is fixed. That means if it returns object always object will be return from that function. What you want to do is you try to benefit from polymorpholism but its cannot be done in such way.

```
var objeto = { 
    row: function(rowId){ 
        return { 
            cell: function(cellClass,newValue){
                  this.set = function (newValue){
                     if(typeof newValue != "undefined"){
                         document.querySelector(rowId+' '+cellClass).innerHTML = val;
                  }
                    }
                this.set(newValue);
                return    document.querySelector(rowId+' '+cellClass).innerHTML;
                }
                //Or just return the value
            }
        }
    }
};
```

So you can use

var currentValue =  objeto.row('#rowid').cell('.cellclass','hello');
or

var currentValue =  objeto.row('#rowid').cell('.cellclass');